# How to put latitude on Y axis in hovmoller plot?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am plotting `hovmoller` plot for three rasters but the function plots the latitude on the x axis and the time on the y axis. normally (much easier to read) latitude is on the Y axis.
Reproducible example:

```
library("rasterVis")
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r2 <- setValues(r2, 1:ncell(r))
St=stack(r,r1,r2)
idx <- seq(as.Date('2008-01-15'), as.Date('2008-1-17'), 'day')
SISmm <- setZ(St, idx)
hovmoller(SISmm, contour=FALSE, panel=panel.levelplot.raster,
          yscale.components=yscale.raster.subticks,
          interpolate=TRUE, par.settings=RdBuTheme)
```

This produces: [image: example plot]

So I want the time to be on the X axis and latitude on the Y axis!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That layout is not implemented in the `rasterVis::hovmoller`
method. Only the common arrangement (time on the y-axis and
latitude/longitude on the x-axis) is available at the moment.

You can try a workaround using the most important parts of the
[function code](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/blob/master/R/hovmoller.R).
For your example, you have to create a `RasterLayer` with the latitude
values. This `RasterLayer` is used by `zonal` to aggregate your
`RasterStack`:

```
library('raster')

dirLayer <- init(SISmm, v='y')
z <- zonal(SISmm, dirLayer, FUN='mean', digits=2)
```

The result is a matrix which is converted to a `data.frame` to be
displayed with `lattice::levelplot`.

```
## Time on the x-axis, latitude on the y-axis
dat <- expand.grid(y=z[,1], x=idx)
dat$z <- as.vector(z[,-1], mode='numeric')

levelplot(z ~ x*y, data=dat,
          xlab='Time', ylab='Latitude',
          panel=panel.levelplot.raster,
          interpolate=TRUE,
          par.settings=RdBuTheme())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. How we add more sub-ticks(more dates on the x axis).

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. How we add more sub-ticks(more dates on the x axis).How to increase the font size of the labels of the legend?Thanks.

Comment: @sacvf For the font size use `colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1.2))`. More details in the help page of `lattice::levelplot`. There is a function in the `latticeExtra` package to display subticks, `xscale.components.subticks`, but it seems to have trouble with dates.

Comment: Why I will have trouble with date? assume that I have more than 20 rasters and want to show sub-tics at each 4 or whatever?